# How to use __has_include correctly?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, include, x11

I am trying to dynamically include x11 libs if any present in system:

```
#if __has_include(<X11/Xlib.h>)
   #include <X11/Xlib.h>
   #include <X11/Xutil.h>
   #include <X11/X.h>

   #define X11_SUPPORT 1
#endif

#ifdef X11_SUPPORT
 <Code for x11 support>
#else
 <Code for no x11 support>
#endif
```

Then when I am building and running the app on the system where X11 libs are definetly present - the code section with no x11 support is executed. The IDE also marks the includes section as inactive, but everything works fine if I just include libraries normally.

The `#if defined __has_include` is interpreted as true

Qt 5.12.8
GCC version 9
C++17

I will be grateful for any help

Comment: __has_include is not standard C++, and anything with __ is considered to be for internal compiler/library use only. I think it is better just to use a conditional compiler define. (-D<symbol>) and use #ifdef <symbol> instead of __has_include

Comment: @PepijnKramer I believe `__has_include` was [standardized in C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include), funny name and all.

Comment: Just make sure this lib header files path is specified with -I

Answer (score 2):

Not that helpful, but: Your example just works for me (Debian testing; gcc 12.2). I am only writing this as an answer so that I can include the output of some commands.

Test file:

```c
#if __has_include(<X11/Xlib.h>)
   #define X11_SUPPORT 1
#endif

#ifdef X11_SUPPORT
 <Code for x11 support>
#else
 <Code for no x11 support>
#endif
```

Compiler invocation and output:

```
$ gcc -E t.c
# 0 "t.c"
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 0 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 0 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "t.c"





 <Code for x11 support>
```

Comment: Maybe I should try gcc 12.2. As I've mentioned I've got version 9, but it is really strange, gcc should have support for this macro from version 7